# How can I ignore case sensitivity in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, case-insensitive

My code below doesn't work:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString = name 
       And ListBox2.Items(i).ToString = founds 
       And ListBox3.Items(i).ToString = foundss Then
             found = (i)
             found1 = found.ToString.Contains(name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <> 1
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: One basic way is just to convert all your strings to lowercase before you compare them.

Comment: I'm new to visual basic. Could you please show me how to do that ?

Comment: There's a function called ToLower. You can find it in the Microsoft documentation, or in the intellisense in visual studio. And you can probably find a lot of existing examples of usage online. Just search a bit

Comment: How does this line make any sense in that context: `found = (i)`?  How is the value of your loop counter ever going to contain anything that requires case-insensitivity when it's a number?

Comment: @ADyson, that's bad advice.  Don't use `ToUpper` or `ToLower` to simulate case-insensitivity because it doesn't always work as expected.  There's no need anyway, given that `String.IndexOf` and `String.Equals` both support case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `String.Contains` with `String.IndexOf`.  `Compare` returns a `Boolean`, not an `Integer`, and it doesn't support case-insensitivity.  `IndexOf` is the one that returns an `Integer` and supports case-insensitivity.  Also, it's `StringComparison`, not `StringComparer`.  Finally, -1 is the result that indicates no match:

```
found1 = found.ToString().IndexOf(name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <> -1
```

As a bonus, here's an extension method that will let you call a `Contains` method that still returns a `Boolean` but also supports case-insensitivity:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function Contains(source As String, value As String, comparisonType As StringComparison) As Boolean
        Return source.IndexOf(value, comparisonType) <> -1
    End Function

End Module
```

E.g.

```
found1 = found.ToString().Contains(name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly your code does. But the String.Contains method returns Boolean and not Integer. So you probably need to change your call to it:

```
found1 = found.ToString.Contains(name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

And to make your other tests case-insensitive, replace the "=" operator with the String.Equals method. Something like:

```
ListBox1.Items(i).ToString().Equals(name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```